# How to check if a callable object is async using inspect module? - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, coroutine, callable

I need an **efficient** and pythonic way to check if a callable object is async or not
`inspect.iscoroutinefunction` fails to identify that, I've tried this:

```
import inspect
        
async def test_func() -> None:
    pass
        
class TestClass:
    async def __call__(self) -> None:
        pass

test_obj = TestClass()
```

when testing:

```
inspect.iscoroutinefunction(test_func)
>>> True

inspect.iscoroutinefunction(test_obj)
>>> False
```

and when testing:

```
inspect.iscoroutinefunction(test_func.__call__)
>>> False

inspect.iscoroutinefunction(test_obj.__call__)
>>> True
```

I can make a helper function like:

```
def is_async(func: Callable) -> bool:
    try:
       return any(map(inspect.iscoroutinefunction, (func, func.__call__)))
    except AttributeError:
        return False
```

But I feel that there's something simpler...

Answer (score 2):

This is from [starlette](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/master/starlette/_utils.py):

```py
import asyncio
import functools
import typing


def is_async_callable(obj: typing.Any) -> bool:
    while isinstance(obj, functools.partial):
        obj = obj.func

    return asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(obj) or (
        callable(obj) and asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(obj.__call__)
    )
```

Comment: It looks like it has some additional checks for partials but almost the same idea. I really appreciate your time and support my friend, thank you.